# SSH config substitutions

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to edit substitutions within ssh_config? I know I can match wildcards such as:

```
Host project*
  HostName %h.domain.com
  User project_user
```

Used thus:

```
ssh project000
rsync data project123:~
```

But are more complex rules possible? How about match to a hostname alias (without explicitly generating every possible combination)?

```
p    -> project000.domain.com
p1   -> project001.domain.com
p123 -> project123.domain.com
```

Just in case: I use both bash and zsh

Answer (score 4):

This is how I'm managing this:

My `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host project*
    ProxyCommand ~/bin/ssh_proxy %h
```

And `~/bin/ssh_proxy`:

```
#!/bin/zsh

function make_host {
    HOST_NUM=${1[8,999]}
    echo project${(l(3)(0))HOST_NUM}
}

exec nc `make_host $1` 22
```

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not possible. OpenSSH doesn't have any instrument to provide these substitutions.

You would have to pre-generate the pairs in advance to your `ssh_config`  for `ssh` to use them.

Or you would have to create bash function that would do the substitution for you, like this:

```
function ssh() {
  ssh "project${1:1}.domain.com"
}
```

It would need some more care to support all your cases with `ssh`, `scp`, `rsync` and passing other parameters also.